# WildCard в сигнатуре метода

Tags: java, generics, core

```
<T extends A> void foo(List<T> list) {}
```

почему такой синтаксис допустим

```
<T super A> void foo(List<T> list) {}
```

но такой нет? Также хотелось бы увидеть объяснение простым языком (если можно с примерами) почему добавление в

```
 List<? extends B> list = new ArrayList<A>();
```

list запрещено, хотя в docs java вижу следующее

```
public boolean add(E e) {
    ensureCapacityInternal(size + 1);  // Increments modCount!!
    elementData[size++] = e;
    return true;
}
transient Object[] elementData; // non-private to simplify nested class access
```

Разве не любой элемент может быть добавлен в массив Object[]? Конкретнее хотелось бы узнать какой механизм препятствует добавлению.

P.S. Иерархия следующая A>B>C
C - потомок B

Прошу, если можете объясните подробнее и как можно проще. Пытался изучить этот момент у Брюса Эккеля, много нагуглил, но толку 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По второй части вопроса. Возьмём такой пример:

```
List<? extends Number> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

По умолчанию создаётся такой объект:

```
new ArrayList<Number>();
```

А мог бы лежать

```
new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

И если мы попробуем добавить, к примеру, 3.5f, то в первом случае всё было бы ок, во втором - ошибка привидения типов. Поэтому в Java существует механизм защиты, при котором ты гарантированно не получишь RuntimeException.

Но в list можно добавить null ---> довольствуйся этим ;/)

Answer (score 5):

Также посоветую ознакомиться с принципом PECS вот [здесь](https://issue.life/questions/2723397).

- P - producer
- E - extends
- C - consumer
- S - super

Вся соль в том, что если вы хотите *взаимодействовать* с элементами переданного списка, вам необходимо использовать конструкцию вида `<? extends SomeClass>`. А если вы хотите *добавить* элементы в переданный список, то тогда вот так: `<? super SomeClass>`.

Для взаимодействия с элементами вы должны быть уверены, что у этих элементов можно вызвать нужный вам метод. Например, есть класс `Cat`, у которого есть метод `meow()`. Передавайте в параметры `<? extends Cat>`, потому что даже если вам передадут список наследников `Cat`, у них всё равно будет метод `meow()`.

С добавлением ситуация обратная. Вы можете добавить в `List<Cat>` экземпляр класса `Lion extends Cat`, но вы не можете добавить в `List<Lion>` экземпляр класса `Cat`. Именно поэтому, если вы хотите добавить в переданный список парочку львов, переданный список должен быть такого вида: `List<? super Lion>`.

Comment: большое спасибо! Всё ясно